# Funcionamieto Fetch de Javascript al realizar peticion a github users

Tags: javascript, html

Quizás alguien pueda ayudarme con este código ya que no logro entender cual es el funcionamiento del mismo, en el cual hago un `fetch` hacia una url (en este caso los users de github), mi intención es que me devuelva los avatares de cada uno de los usuarios lo cual lo hace, pero el problema que tengo es que no termino de entender que argumento que tengo que pasarle a la función a la hora de llamarla, ni por que me genera varios avatares, tal parece de manera aleatoria, no se si logro hacerme entender, espero que alguien pueda echarme una mano, saludos.

```js
async function getAvatarPhoto(names) {
    let jobs = [];

    for (let name of names) {
        let job = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`).then(
                successResponse => {
                    if (successResponse.status != 200) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return successResponse.json();
                    }
                },
                failResponse => {
                    return null;
                }
            )
            .then((myJson) => {
                console.log(myJson.avatar_url);

            });
        jobs.push(job);
    }

    let results = await Promise.all(jobs);

    return results;
}

console.log(getAvatarPhoto("Agus"));
```

Comment: No se entiende claramente la pregunta. Podrías explicarte de mejor manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que espera es un array de usuarios, no un string. Si le pasas como parámetro `getAvatarPhoto(["Agus"])`, verás que sólo hace una petición y devuelve la URL del avatar del usuario `Agus`.

Ahora mismo está tratando el String "Agus" como un iterable y al iterar el bucle

```
for (let name of names) { ...}
```

está usando cada letra como un nombre de usuario:

```js
let names = "Agus";

for (let name of names) console.log(`name vale ${name}`);
```

```js
async function getAvatarPhoto(names) {
    let jobs = [];

    for (let name of names) {
        let job = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`).then(
                successResponse => {
                    if (successResponse.status != 200) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return successResponse.json();
                    }
                },
                failResponse => {
                    return null;
                }
            )
            .then((myJson) => {
                console.log(myJson.avatar_url);

            });
        jobs.push(job);
    }

    let results = await Promise.all(jobs);

    return results;
}

console.log(getAvatarPhoto("Agus"));
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que a tu función getAvatarPhoto espera una array de nombre y tu le estas pasando un string y lo interpreta como una array y te saca un avatar por cada letra de tu nombre. La forma de realizarlo seria esta:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

let names = [];
names.push('sssolammm');
names.push('Agus');

async function getAvatarPhoto(names) {
    let jobs = [];

    for (let name of names) {
        let job = fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`).then(
                successResponse => {
                    if (successResponse.status != 200) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        return successResponse.json();
                    }
                },
                failResponse => {
                    return null;
                }
            )
            .then((myJson) => {
                console.log(myJson.avatar_url);

            });
        jobs.push(job);
    }

    let results = await Promise.all(jobs);

    return results;
}

console.log(getAvatarPhoto('Agus'));
```